# E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process error Android Studio

Tags: android, smsmanager

I wrote a program to send SMS that crashes when executed

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btnsend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsend);
    final EditText edtnum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtnum);
    final EditText edttext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edttext);



    btnsend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) { 
            String phoneNo=edtnum.getText().toString();
            String message=edttext.getText().toString();
            SmsManager manager=SmsManager.getDefault();
            manager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo,null,message,null,null);

        }
    });

}
```

}

**The application crashes when it hits the button and gives this error**

> 2019-09-09 10:30:33.384 2104-2104/com.example.video60
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.video60, PID: 2104
>       java.lang.SecurityException: Sending SMS message: uid 10086 does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS.
>           at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1942)
>           at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1888)
>           at com.android.internal.telephony.ISms$Stub$Proxy.sendTextForSubscriber(ISms.java:789)
>           at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessageInternal(SmsManager.java:329)
>           at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:312)
>           at com.example.video60.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:41)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24697)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Comment: post your androidManifest.xml

Comment: isn't error `Sending SMS message: uid 10086 does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS` self-explaining?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your android manifest, declare the following :

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />`

as your exception is telling you:

> Sending SMS message: uid 10086 does not have
>   android.permission.SEND_SMS.

your app does not have permission to send SMS's

Have a look at this for additional info: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview

My answer will work for api's 22 and below, for anything higher you will have to request permission, which you can find here : https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

something like this :

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // Permission is not granted
}

// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Permission is not granted
    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
        // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
    } else {
        // No explanation needed; request the permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
} else {
    // Permission has already been granted
}
```

Comment: I did it but it didn't work out

Comment: see my update, also post your androidManifest.xml @rezamotahari